# How to export the activity of my phone in the last 8 hours?

Tags: android

Is it possible to download or export the activity or logs of my phone in the last 8 hours?

My phone has been stolen but was found shortly after and I would like to know what apps were started and what exactly happened throughout that time. Is this possible?

Comment: Youd may want to ask this question in [Android Stack Exchange](https://android.stackexchange.com/) instead

Comment: not really.... but you can implement a way to just imput the users activity into a DB... Firebase would be a great tool for this. I am using Firebase to see what app users are searching for. I am going to be using this information to provide more content later on. b ut as soon as a search happens, my database gets the info. based on what the user clicks, u can get something to the DB.